# как вывести значение поля

Tags: xml, simplexml

```
<form_result>
<field>
    <data name="КодЗаявки">a1</data>
    <data name="НомерЗаявки">1</data>
    <data name="СтатусЗаявки">Зарегистрирована</data>
    <data name="ПричинаОтменыЗаявки"/>
    </field>
<field>
    <data name="КодЗаявки">vg3</data>
    <data name="НомерЗаявки">2</data>
    <data name="СтатусЗаявки">В исполнении</data>
    <data name="ПричинаОтменыЗаявки"/>
</field>
```

получаю такой объект

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#121 (2) {
["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["name"]=>
            string(9) "КодЗаявки"
    }
[0]=>
    string(2) "a1"
```

}

атрибут выводится так $data["name"], а как здесь вывести "a1"?

Comment: Покажите код как вы получили `$data`.

Comment: если  `$data["name"]` выводит `код заявки`, то `$data` выведет `a1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменную $xml положили SimpleXML объект, например так:

```
$xmlContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <form_result>
    <field>
        <data name="КодЗаявки">a1</data>
        <data name="НомерЗаявки">1</data>
        <data name="СтатусЗаявки">Зарегистрирована</data>
        <data name="ПричинаОтменыЗаявки"/>
    </field>
    <field>
        <data name="КодЗаявки">vg3</data>
        <data name="НомерЗаявки">2</data>
        <data name="СтатусЗаявки">В исполнении</data>
        <data name="ПричинаОтменыЗаявки"/>
    </field>
    </form_result>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlContent);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
```

тогда

```
echo (string)$xml->field[0]->data[0]['name']; //КодЗаявки
echo (string)$xml->field[0]->data[0]; //a1

echo (string)$xml->field[1]->data[2]; //В исполнении
```

Или например циклом:

```
foreach ($xml->field as $field) {
    foreach ($field->data as $data) {
        echo (string)$data['name'].': '.(string)$data.'<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}

/*
КодЗаявки: a1
НомерЗаявки: 1
СтатусЗаявки: Зарегистрирована
ПричинаОтменыЗаявки: 

КодЗаявки: vg3
НомерЗаявки: 2
СтатусЗаявки: В исполнении
ПричинаОтменыЗаявки
*/
```

Comment: а как вывести в цикле? <code>$dom=new DOMDocument();
 $dom->load("test2.xml");
 $xml=simplexml_import_dom($dom);
 foreach($xml->field as $f)
  foreach($f->data as $d)
   var_dump($d);</code>

Comment: Добавил цикл в ответ